# Two questions on stable groups

Tags: model-theory

I'm going over Marker's Model Theory. I have two questions in the "$\omega$-Stable groups" section.

1. In Lemma 7.1.12: $p\in S_1(G)$ and $\psi(v)$ defines $G^0$. He claims that there exists a $b\in G$ such that $\psi(b^{-1}v)\in p$. Why is that?
2. Why are there only a finite number of types of maximal Morley rank, that is of rank equal to the rank of the group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1., notice that $p(v)\cup p(v')\vdash \psi(v'^{-1}v)$, so for some finite $p_0\subseteq p$ we have $p(v)\cup p_0(v')\vdash \psi(v'^{-1}v)$ and $p_0$ is of course satisfied in $G$.

For 2., if there are infinitely many points (types) of a given Cantor-Bendixson rank (Morley rank) at least $\alpha<\infty$ in a given clopen set (the set of types satisfying a formula, like the entire $S_1(G)$), then the rank of the set is at least $\alpha+1$. On the other hand, $\omega$-stability is equivalent to statement that the Morley rank is bounded.

Comment: 2. Can you elaborate? If $\phi_p,\phi_q$ are two formulas of minimal ranks in two types $p,q$. Why should $\phi_p(G)$ be disjoint from $\phi_q(G)$? (As needed for the rank of the union of the infinite number of types to be grow$

Comment: @Yatir: If I understand correctly, they obviously don't have to be, as $\phi_p\lor \phi_q$ also has minimal rank if the two happen to coincide, but I'm not sure how it relates. I'm not sure what definition of Morley rank are you working with, but I've always found that seeing it as exactly the Cantor-Bendixson rank in an $\aleph_0$-saturated extension to be the most intuitive. In particular, an infinite family of points of rank $\alpha$ converges (on a subsequence) to a point of rank $\alpha+1$ (due to compactness). You might try to translate it to a statement about formulas&types if you like.

Comment: Correction: the infinite family might not a priori converge on a subsequence if the space is too large to be metrisable, but it certainly does have a limit point.